# Getting unexpected keyword argument 'tokenizer_class' while running Pytorch project

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to run this project ([Co-Attack](https://github.com/adversarial-for-goodness/Co-Attack)) on my Ubuntu.

I have installed all the dependencies mentioned in [requirement.txt](https://github.com/adversarial-for-goodness/Co-Attack/blob/main/requirements.txt) and added the required data in the [config path](https://github.com/adversarial-for-goodness/Co-Attack/blob/main/configs/Retrieval_flickr.yaml). Besides, I added Finetuned checkpoint and added the path during running the command.

```
python RetrievalEval.py --adv 0 --gpu 0 --cls --config configs/Retrieval_flickr.yaml --output_dir output/Retrieval_flickr --checkpoint checkpoints/flickr30k.pth
```

I am getting the below error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/projects/AdvAttack/Co-Attack/RetrievalEval.py", line 17, in <module>
    from models.model_retrieval import ALBEF
  File "/home/user/projects/AdvAttack/Co-Attack/models/model_retrieval.py", line 3, in <module>
    from models.xbert import BertConfig, BertModel
  File "/home/user/projects/AdvAttack/Co-Attack/models/xbert.py", line 833, in <module>
    class BertModel(BertPreTrainedModel):
  File "/home/user/projects/AdvAttack/Co-Attack/models/xbert.py", line 871, in BertModel
    @add_code_sample_docstrings(
TypeError: add_code_sample_docstrings() got an unexpected keyword argument 'tokenizer_class'
```

After analyzing the error, I found it cannot load model ALBEF although the [model exists](https://github.com/adversarial-for-goodness/Co-Attack/blob/main/models/model_retrieval.py) in the actual place.

What am I missing to run this project?